# D3- How to display the ticks of a xAxis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I can't find the way for displaying the ticks of a xAxis if those are placed in the far bottom of the svg-canvas.

The variable I want to show are quarters of different years, so I converted an array of strings ["1947-01-01","1947-04-01",...] into an array of js date  objects [Mon Apr 01 1957 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT+01:00), Mon Jul 01 1957 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00),...]

I built the xAxis

```
const xScale=d3.scalePoint()
                    .domain(dates) // dates is a array of date objects
                    .range([0,w])

const xAxis=d3.axisBottom(xScale);
```

And finally I set a group

```
svg.append("g")
            .attr("class","axis")
            .attr(`transform`,`translate(0,${h})`) // h is the height of the canvas
            .call(xAxis)
             .ticks(4) // It does not work  in this code
```

I tried to apply the command ticks, but it  does not work in this code.
On the other hand, I do not know how to display the ticks below the xAxis when that is at the bottom line of the canvas.

Comment: What does `w` stand for?

Comment: w is the width of the canvas

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with your scales and the chaining of the .ticks() method. According to the [d3.axis documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis), `.ticks()` should be used called on your axis. Try making the following changes to your `xAxis`.

```
 const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(4);
```

And remove `.ticks()` when you render the x-axis,

```
svg.append('g')
  .attr('class','axis')
  .attr('transform',`translate(0,${h})`) 
  .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: Yes, that works with the yAxis=d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(4) I got the desired result, but when I tried with the xAxis=d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(4) it is no working. Might be it is something wrong converting the array of strings to array of date objects, so, the array of date objects is not suitable for applying the command **ticks**

Comment: Hmm.. If you are using it on time/date, it might be better to use` scaleTime()` instead of `scalePoint`? Have you tried scaleTime?

Comment: I tried scaleTime() now and the result is that all the ticks disappear but one in the far left that displays the last two figures of the first year. So, the first date object is: **Wed Jan 01 1947 00.00.00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), ..** and the tick showed in the far left (the only one showed)  is **47**